# Non coherent detection BFSK demodulation?

Tags: matlab, digital-communications, modulation, demodulation, fsk

I am simulating BER performance of BFSK under AWGN and Rayleigh fading, BFSK has two symbols one entirely on the real plane while other on the complex plane for representing let's say zero and one, that is how the constellation of BFSK looks like.

```
s=data + j*(~data); %Baseband BFSK modulation
```

Now let's say we added AWGN (N) and Rayleigh fading (h) as well.

```
Rx= h*x + N;
```

Now when I tried to detect it on the receiving side I will have to divide this entire `Rx` by an `h`, well that makes sense.

My entire graphs for the BER curve match non-coherent detection for FSK.

It exactly matched the theory, Eb/N0 vs. BER for BFSK over Rayleigh Channel.

**How to do the same for Non-coherent detection?**

If I do not divide `Rx` by `h`, `Rx/h`, I get a few very very bad results and that doesn't match anything. Theory tells us that In non-coherent detection, there's no prioir knowledge about the channel impulse response at the receiver.

In coherent systems, the receiver needs phase information of the transmitter (the carrier phase) to recover the transmitted data at the receiver side. I haven't used any such thing but still simulation results for BER matched with that of theory for Coherent FSK.

Can someone here help me with this?

- By not diving by `h`, will I get better results for Non coherent FSK?
- Whether BPSK or BFSK every time we need to divide `h*x + N` by an `h` to  get results that match theory.

Comment: I'm confused. You win very little, if anything, by having phase information on the channel in the classical (B)FSK case – your receiver really doesn't care about the phase at all. You cannot compare that to BPSK, where the phase is the actually information-carrying entity.

Comment: Your `s`, however, doesn't look like FSK at all – it's just a BPSK of amplitude $\sqrt2$, rotated by 45° (assuming `data` just means "a bit of data mapped to $\pm 1$).

Comment: For BPSK symbols have 180-degrees phase shift, either both symbols at complex or both symbols at real, this definitely is not BPSK at 45 degrees rotation if one is at zero while other is at 90. 

"You win very little, if anything, by having phase information" might be true that I win very little but all I am trying to do is achieve BER curves for non-coheret FSK,  BFSK over Rayleigh and AWGN so divided s or Rx by h, If I don't it might be  but curves tells very sad story that matches absolutely nothing

Comment: I achieved it for coherent but not for non-cohernt so how to do that? Should I not divide it by h ?

Comment: seriously, your `s` is not FSK, it's a PSK or QAM. For `data=0`, you get `s= 1j`, and for `data=1` you get `s=1`, and  thus you're right, it's not just rotated BPSK, I typed to hastily; it has a simple decision boundary, and it's the diagonal of the upper right quadrant of the complex plane, and that is just the 45° shifted decision boundary of BPSK.

Comment: For BPSK 360/2 = 180 degrees. 0 and 1 has to be 180- degree apart. Now my 0 is at angle 0 and 1 is at angle 90 there phase difference of 90 degree how is that BPSK ? You can’t even call it QPSK as it has just two bits and not 4 at single time period and how it satisfied the BER Curves?

Comment: I’d love to know ... how ? It would have bpsk if one I place one bit at -90 degree while next at + 90, google constellation diagram of BFSK

Comment: As I admitted, it's not a BPSK, but it's a two-point PSK; nothing about this is frequency shifting. I really don't understand how you're concluding it is FSK?

Comment: If I leave it simply one and a zero without manipulating it will that be bfsk?

Comment: can you pls tell ?

Comment: I agree with Marcus- For this to be FSK you would need to rotate from one point on the constellation to the next over the symbol duration (frequency is a change in phase versus a change in time). If you rotate ±90° in one symbol duration with linear phase versus time, this is Minimum Shift Keying (a form of FSK)-- it is the minimum you need to rotate and keep the two frequencies orthogonal.   If you smooth the phase transitions with a Gaussian filter, you get Gaussian Minimum Shift Keying which has better out of band emission performance due to the smoothing of the otherwise abrubt transitions

Comment: Thankyou @DanBoschen Can you please tell me I am a bit confused, Is it correct? And how can I do same for non-coherent as the graph for BER matches exactly that of Noncoherent FSK over Rayleigh

Comment: @LeonhardEulerfan not at all, as I've been saying – FSK doesn't benefit at all from channel phase knowledge, so the BER is identical for non-coherent and coherent reception.

Comment: @DanBoschen okay forget about PSK and other concepts, tell me what I am doing 1+0j and 0+1j is that BFSK or not ? 

And BER isn't same, go to matlab apps in upper bar and signal processing and communication field we have BER, please draw theoretical graphs for FSK and see what it is not the same for coherent and non-cohernet at all.